# TFF : every client do a pretrain function instead of build_federated_averaging_process

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I would like that every client train his model with a function `pretrain`that I wrote below :

```
def pretrain(model):
 
    resnet_output = model.output
    layer1 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnet_output)
    layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=zdim*2, activation='relu')(layer1)
    model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=zdim)(layer2)

    model = tf.keras.Model(model.input, model_output)  
    
    iterations_per_epoch = determine_iterations_per_epoch()
    total_iterations = iterations_per_epoch*num_epochs
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)

    checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(1), optimizer=optimizer, net=model)
    manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint, pretrain_save_path, max_to_keep=10)
   
    
    current_epoch = tf.cast(tf.floor(optimizer.iterations/iterations_per_epoch), tf.int64)
    batch = client_data(0)
    batch = client_data(0).batch(2)

    epoch_loss = []
    for (image1, image2) in batch:

        loss, gradients = train_step(model, image1, image2)
        epoch_loss.append(loss)
       
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
      
       # if tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(epoch, current_epoch+1)):
        print("Loss after epoch {}: {}".format(current_epoch, sum(epoch_loss)/len(epoch_loss)))
        #print("Learning rate: {}".format(learning_rate(optimizer.iterations)))

        epoch_loss = []
        current_epoch += 1
        if current_epoch % 50 == 0:
             save_path = manager.save() 
             print("Saved model for epoch {}: {}".format(current_epoch, save_path))
    save_path = manager.save()
    model.save("model.h5") 
    model.save_weights("saved_weights.h5")
```

But as we know that TFF has a predefined function :

```
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(...)
```

So please, how can I proceed ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that one could proceed along similar lines.

First it is important to note that TFF is functional--one can use things like writing to / reading from files to manage state (as TF allows this), but it is not in the interface TFF exposes to users--while something involving writing to / reading from a file (IE, manipulating state without passing it through function parameters and results), this should at best be considered an implementation detail. It's something that TFF does not encourage.

By slightly refactoring your code above, however, I think this kind of application can fit quite nicely in TFF's programming model. We will want to define something like:

```py
@tff.tf_computation
@tf.function
def pretrain_client_model(model, client_dataset):
  # perhaps do dataset processing you want...
  for batch in client_dataset:
    # do model training
  return model.weights() # or some tensor structure representing the trained model weights
```

Once your implementation looks something like this, you will be able to wire it in to a custom iterative process. The canned function you mention (`build_federated_averaging_process`) really just constructs an instance of [`tff.templates.IterativeProcess`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/templates/IterativeProcess); you are always, however, free to write your own instance of this class.

Several tutorials take us through this process, [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/building_your_own_federated_learning_algorithm) probably being the simplest. For a finished code example of a standalone iterative process implementation, see [`simple_fedavg.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py).

Comment: Thank you for your response, this mean that I must use Federated Core ? Because I'm not interested with orchestration logic, nor with server update and client update... I would like only that each client do a specific training (function pretrain ).